# Simple expression for $(-\Delta)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ in the spatial domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, fourier-transform, pseudo-differential-operators

I can write the harmonic and biharmonic operators as:

$$-\Delta = -\sum_i \partial_{ii}, \quad (-\Delta)^2 = \sum_i\sum_j \partial_{ii}\partial_{jj}$$.

Is there such a simple expression for $(-\Delta)^{\frac{3}{2}}$? In 1D I would guess it is $-\frac{d^3}{dx^3}$. Is this correct? Would then $-\sum_i \partial_i\sum_j\partial_{jj}$ be the generalization for higher dimensions. I believe that $(-\Delta)^{\alpha}$ can be represented as $(4\pi^2|\omega|)^{\alpha}$ in the Fourier domain, but I wanted to have an expression in terms of the derivatives in the spatial domain, if such exists.

Would this then generalize to other $\alpha = \frac{n}{2}, \, n \in\mathbb{N}$?

Edit: I found this review: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09767
which covers quite s lot. Both of my guesses seem to have been wrong.

Comment: Your guess for 1D is not correct, since all powers of $(-\Delta)$ are self adjoint in $L^2$ (with the right boundary conditions, while odd derivatives are not.

Comment: @HansEngler Are you aware of any references that discuss approximations of $(-\Delta)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ in the spatial domain using partial derivatives?

Comment: No, since $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$ is necessarily a nonlocal operator. In 1-D it's the Hilbert transform applied to the first derivative.

Comment: @HansEngler But it does decay quickly enough as far as I know, e.g. $(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ in the spatial domain. So couldn't it be approximated by truncating a series of partial derivatives to which $(-\Delta)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ expands?

Comment: No, clearly not. You can have a function $u$  that vanishes on some open bounded set but $(-\Delta)^{1/2} u \ne 0$ on that set. It's wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a simple expression as Hans Engler mentioned. There are various formulations: [What Is the Fractional Laplacian?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09767) beyond the spectral one, but none seems to be too useful for compactness in the spatial domain.

I also figured out that this cannot be rewritten in terms of differential operators in the spatial domain because of the modulus in the Fourier domain. So that's the main thing causing problems there. Without the modulus one gets the odd derivatives as expected.